# Insert text into textarea

Tags: javascript

How would I insert text on page load into this text area:

```
<textarea name="orderNotes" cols="115" rows="3"></textarea>
```

I have attempted:

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementsByClassName('orderNotes');
console.log(myTextarea);
myTextarea.value += "text to add to the textarea";
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="orderNotes" cols="115" rows="3"></textarea>
```

Comment: <textarea name="orderNotes" cols="115" rows="3"></textarea>

Comment: attribute `name` != `className`

Comment: make sure also that your element is rendered first before executing your code on page load

Comment: Wrap your code like so: onload=function(){ /* your code goes here */ }

Answer (score 2):

Your js code should work if you access the `[0]` element of the array returned by `getElementsByTagName()` and add a `class` attribute to your markup.

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementsByClassName('orderNotes')[0];
myTextarea.value += "text to add to the textarea";

<textarea name="orderNotes" class="orderNotes" cols="115" rows="3"></textarea>
```

But a safer approach would be to set an `id` attribute and access it with `getElementById()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()`.

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementById('orderNotes');
myTextarea.value += "text to add to the textarea";

<textarea name="orderNotes" id="orderNotes" cols="115" rows="3"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given your `<textarea>` any class at all, so `.getElementsByClassName()` won't be useful unless you do:

```
<textarea name="orderNotes" class="orderNotes">
```

Once you do that, you'll have to deal with the fact that `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements, not just one element.

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementsByClassName('orderNotes')[0];
```

That sets your variable to the first one found. If you want to identify that `<textarea>` uniquely, you can give it an id:

```
<textarea name="orderNotes" id="orderNotes">
```

and then use `.getElementById()` which returns just one element (or nothing):

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementById("orderNotes");
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic example with Javascript:

```js
var textArea = document.myform.inputtext.value;
textArea += "your text";
document.myform.inputtext.value = textArea;
```

```html
<form name="myform">
<textarea name="inputtext"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes you are right @Pointy, I have edited my code. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to select by a class name, which requires the use of the `class` html attribute. You can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) here to get by attribute name.

```
var myTextarea = document.querySelector("textarea[name='orderNotes']");
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementByClassName returns array of items as more object can share the class. So you should access it by its index (myTextarea[0].value - it you know it's the only element with this class) or better use id and access it with document.getElementById('id'):

javascript:

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementsById('orderNotes');
consol.log(myTextarea);
myTextarea.value += "text to add to the textarea";
```

html:

```
<textarea id="orderNotes" cols="115" rows="3"></textarea>
```